# User Uploaded CSS safe?

Tags: css, security

Is there anything tricky someone could do with user-uploaded CSS to harm a site? If I wanted to allow users to upload/share their own CSS themes to a site, is there anything I should look for or disallow?

EDIT: Assume I know how to check if it's a valid CSS file etc. I'm looking for CSS specific exploits I need to avoid.

Comment: No, it's not safe. There are quite a few malicious possibilities.

Comment: I was looking for less of a yes/no and more examples of what to look for.

Comment: I think you should define your concerns more clearly. Does a crappy or broken stylesheet fall into the "tricky" category? How about one that says `*{display:none}`? I assume that you mean something like expose sensitive data or send data to a third party, but folks here seem to be concerned with just making the page ugly or broken (or say swear words with `:after` content :D).

Comment: By the way, try `*{display:block}` some time and check out what happens. Not pretty. Try it in Firebug on this page.

Comment: If they want to f up their page, that's their business. I just wanted to make sure they can't execute code for the most part, and if they shared this CSS theme with others, it couldn't grab their cookies or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you parse the file for valid CSS a hacker could still be malicious by using something like [:before and :after](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html). To ensure security you will want to whitelist a subset of css properties & selectors in your validation.

Comment: +1 for whitelisting but I'd add selectors to the list as well as properties, there's no reason for half measures when you're being paranoid.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what could possibly be malicious about `:before` or `:after` content? Maybe I'm not thinking of "malicious" in the same sense you are?

Comment: @mu-is-too-short I agree on the selectors, I'll edit my answer. @Wesley-Murch I thought you might be able to add javascript code using :before or :after but after looking into it, it seems this is not the case. I presume the op only wants users to style the website, not add content so it could still be considered malicious.

Comment: @Wesley: You could include a `url(nefarious_content_or_tracking_trick)` in `:before` or `:after`, you could also use the same `url()` trick for `background-image` and such.

Comment: I had to downvote, I'm not sure how you expect to adequately parse a user supplied stylesheet for "safe" selectors, properties, or values. For all we know, the user could try to upload a javascript, php, image, or PDF file with a `.css` extension, or just a mangled text file. How are we to parse this? You say it as if it is trivial. @mu - Excellent point on the `url()` aspect, but as you noted - it's not limited to before/after.

Comment: @Wesley: Ever heard of a CSS parser? If you're whitelisting then you're parsing and your parser would complain if you tried to feed it a PDF file or anything else that wasn't CSS. If you whitelist the selectors and the properties properly, then you should be okay.

Comment: @muistooshort: Actually no, I've never heard of anyone doing that. Happy to remove the downvote in light of this being feasible (albeit undisclosed in the post).

Comment: @Wesley: I've done it several times. Usually just `style` attributes while whitelisting HTML (elements and attributes of course) but I've done whole stylesheets too.

Comment: @Wesley http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364302/how-to-preform-whitelist-based-css-filtering-in-php

Answer (score 3):

I believe standard CSS, parsed in a standard way is safe.  However, through various non-standard extensions [CSS is unsafe](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CssAllowsArbitraryCodeExecution).

It's not just CSS that is unsafe, due to the fact that some browsers ignore RFC 2616 and sniff the content type instead of respecting the `Content-Type` header, it is possible to trick some browsers into embedding JavaScript hidden within static image files.

Even if you work around these particular issues, there's nothing stopping browser vendors from screwing you over in other ways without you realising.

As a general rule, I would not allow untrusted users to upload files unless I gave each user their own subdomain and ensured that any cookies on the main site were limited to the `www` host.  This makes it look to the browser that each user has their own separate site with their own separate security context, so even if they manage to execute code, it doesn't compromise anything.

Answer (score 2):

They can include an .htc file which is essentially Javascript. Actually, it doesn't even need to be in .htc file, you can write Javascript in CSS using expression(). And also (although this is given), they can mess with your site by hiding/showing stuff inappropriately.

Comment: Wouldn't they have to upload the .htc file as well to pull this off? I could be wrong but I didn't think it was possible to serve htc cross domain.

Comment: @Wesley I was assuming if this is to provide user the ability to skin the site, it would provide a way to upload assets as well? Regardless, you can also write Javascript in an expression().

Answer (score 1):

You primarily need to be careful on what is being uploaded.  If you do some kind of sanity check, that it is valid CSS, you should be fine, but if you just allow any old file to be uploaded, someone could sneak in some java script or other malicious code.

The actual type is not harmful, but the whole upload concept is the problem as it allows attackers to deliver a payload you wouldn't expect.

But I would say as long as you check off your security checklist and validate your content to be at least some css, you should be fine.