# Applying a CSS whitelist to HTML in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Lets say I have the following `$string...`

```
<span style='text-decoration:underline; display:none;'>Some text</span>
```

I only want to allow the style `text-decoration`, so I want a PHP function like the following...

```php
$string = stripStyles($string, array("text-decoration"));
```

Similar to [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), but using an array instead. So `$string` will now be...

```
<span style='text-decoration:underline;'>Some text</span>
```

I am using Cake, so if this can be done with Sanitize then all the better.

Comment: I think you will need PHP's DOMDocument() Object for this.

Comment: Why is this getting off-topic votes to Programmers.SE? What am I missing?

Comment: @Michael: I did wrong close vote and someone followed me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preform whitelist-based CSS filtering in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1364302)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preform whitelist-based CSS filtering in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364302/how-to-preform-whitelist-based-css-filtering-in-php)

Comment: Hmmm, it _is_ the same question, but I'm not fond of the answer there...

Comment: @wrikken - Sounds like a good opportunity to offer a better solution. :)

Comment: Agreed, a working function would be nice, not some psuedo code.

Comment: @Wrikken: Unanswered question does not mean that you can create duplicate ;)

Comment: @Jared: was counting down until someone said it indeed :) As it should be. Now, to find the time, and be complete, hm.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, but you should be able to do it with `DOMDocument`.  This should get you started, but it's likely to require some serious tweaking.

```
// Load your html string
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_string);

// Get all the <span> tags
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName("span");

// Loop over the span tags
foreach($spans as $span) {

  // If they have a style attribute that contains "text-decoration:"
  // attempt to replace the contents of the style attribute with only the text-decoration component.
  if ($style = $span->getAttribute("style")) {
    if (preg_match('/text-decoration:([^;]*);/i', $style)) {
      $span->setAttribute("style", preg_replace('/^(.*)text-decoration:([^;]*);(.*)$/i', "text-decoration:$2;", $style);
    }
    // Otherwise, erase the style attribute
    else $span->setAttribute("style", "");
  }
}

$output = $dom->saveHTML;
```

It's maybe better to attempt to parse the style attributes by `explode()`ing on `;`

```
// This replaces the inner contents of the foreach ($spans as $span) above...

// Instead of the preg_replace()
$styles = explode(";", $style);
$replaced_style = FALSE;
foreach ($styles as $s) {
 if (preg_match('/text-decoration/', $s) {
   $span->setAttribute("style", $s);
   $replaced_style = TRUE;
 }
 //  If a text-decoration wasn't found, empty out the style
 if (!$replaced_style) $span->setAttribute("style", "");
}
```

Comment: @jchavannes you seem to want a lot

Comment: Try using xpath with `//*[@style]` if going the DOM route.

Comment: There is, of course, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php/

Comment: @jchavannes The above is a large and complicated block of code, and should be more than enough to send you in the right direction if you aren't in over your head with this project requirement.  Wrap it in a `function()` and replace the `getElementsByTagName()` with an xpath query as suggested in the comments if needed.